# Uniform limit of series of nearly compactly supported functions is nearly compactly supported

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, uniform-convergence, banach-algebras

Let there be a series of continuous functions $u_n\colon \Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with nearly compact support, that is for $\varepsilon>0$ the set $u_n^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon))$ is compact, and let that series be uniformly convergent to $u$ according to the sup-norm.

So, continuity (thereby closedness for the above pre-image) for $u$ transfers by uniform convergence, but how do I show, technically, the boundedness of the above pre-image for $u$?

Why is there a unit in the ring those continuous functions with nearly compact support form if, and only if, $\Omega$ is compact?

Comment: Your second question seems to b e totally unrelated. You may want to ask it a a sepqrate question (with cntext of its own)

Comment: What is $\Omega$? Which ring are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, made an edit. I mean the ring the continuous functions with nearly compact support form when equipped with component-wise addition and (scalar) multiplication. The context of the question is that I have to show that that ring, further, forms a banach-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.
For large enough $n$,  $\|u_n-u\|<\frac \epsilon2$.
$$|u(x)|\ge \epsilon \implies |u_n(x)|\ge \frac \epsilon 2,$$
i.e.,  $$u^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus (-\epsilon,\epsilon))\subseteq u_n^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus (-\tfrac\epsilon2,\tfrac\epsilon2))$$
and the latter set is compact.

---

Note that the function given by $f(x)=\frac1{1+\|x\|}$ is nearly compactly supported (and continuous). A unit element $e$ in your ring must have the property that $e(x)f(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in\Omega$, hence $e(x)=1$ for all $x\in \Omega$. 
With $\epsilon:=1$, we have $e^{-1}(\Bbb R\setminus(-\epsilon,\epsilon)=\Omega$, and this must be compact if $e$ is nearly compactly supported.